# Cannot Refresh RDLC Report DataSet

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I have tried multiple solutions in different posts to no avail, so please forgive me for being redundant. I have a dataset for an RDLC PDF report in ASP.NET using VS2010. I have changed the SQL statement to return two additonal columns to an existing set. I have stepped through the debugger and verified the two column are being returned with the proper data. However, I cannot get the Dataset to refresh with these new columns. And when I add them in the XML manually, the fields are just blank on the report.

Please help

Comment: Disregard. Restarted a third time, now it is working correctly. Not sure why the third time is a charm. Thanks